# Cannot find module requirejs when installed globally

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I have installed `requirejs` globally, but `node` says it can't find it.

```
# node tools/mapconv.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'requirejs'
    ...

# cat mapconv.js
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
...
```

The module is definitely installed:

```
# npm ls -g | grep requirejs
├── requirejs@2.1.6
```

I have cleared the NPM cache, but no change. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: What's the context in which you cannot find it? Have you simply tried reinstalling the package?

Comment: @m90: Updated the question with some more info. I tried reinstalling requirejs. Didn't help.

Comment: Is requirejs included in your package.json. Not sure if thats the issue or if its required but it might be.

Comment: @JasonM: Good call, but it's not an NPM package - just a standalone script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your `NODE_PATH` environment variable is set. To find out where to set it to, run:

```
npm install --global --verbose requirejs
```

set node path to the dir ending in node_modules

Comment: Thank you, @Lyn! Just to clarify, I'm on a Mac, so I had to add `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to my `~/.bash_profile` script.

Comment: Many thanks @Lyn Headley and @alekop! If you don't want to hardwire the NPM prefix into your bash config you can also use `export NODE_PATH=$(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules`

Comment: What about on an IIS system?